# Receive email from PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, email, post

I have no experience with php, I only do front-end development. I want to set up this contact form to send me emails. I am using an [example from htmldog.](http://htmldog.com/techniques/formtoemail/)

This is what i have so far:

```
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
      <div class="col-md-5 left">
        <input name="sender" type="text" class="name" placeholder="FULL NAME">
        <input name="senderEmail" type="text" class="email" placeholder="EMAIL">
        <input name="senderPhoneNumber" type="text" class="number" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 right">
        <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="SEND">
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="test@mailinator.com";
    $subject="Contact form";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $senderPhoneNumber=$_POST["senderPhoneNumber"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Ime: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nTelefon: $senderPhoneNumber\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
}

?>
```

All of this is located in the contact.php file which displays the whole contact page. The php part is at the very beginning of the file, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.

EDIT: sorry for not being clear enough, the form is not working for some reason, i was wondering if its maybe some obvious coding error or do you see any other reason why it wouldn't work?

Its shared hosting.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: so is it working? is this hosted locally? are you using a development server, shared or dedicated hosting?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header injection...

Comment: @PeeHaa help me fix that, how can i get more secure?

Comment: @atmd it's shared hosting.

Comment: If I where you I'd contact your hosting support, there are many thing that could effect it, saying the form 'isnt working' doesnt give much to go on, you might need to auth a smtp, you might not have email set up on your host, you might not have certain php extensions installed. stick a die('about to send mail'); just above the mail() call, if you see that then you have got to the mail function fine, after that the best bet is to check you server/smtp logs

Comment: @Damir have you checked out what it is and how to prevent it yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck this issue before. While it looks seemingly simple, the PHP mail function needs pre-configuration.

[PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) works only when you have an SMTP server on your machine. So most probably, while the code seems to be correct, it would not work on your local host (it may still work on shared hosting with out any change).

You can choose an alternative such as [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) with your own SMTP settings.